# Send Java array as JavaScript parameter

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp

**Problem**

I send an array from **StarConroller.java** to **Star.jsp** page by `**model.addAttribute**`

StarConroller.java

```
List<Object> books = booksService.findAll();
model.addAttribute("books ", books);
```

I want to send this array of books to **Star.js** by clicking the "Show books" button in **Star.jsp**

Star.jsp

```
<button type="button" onclick="show(`${books}`)">Show books</button>
```

Star.js

```
function show(books) {
    console.log(books);
}
```

**Issue**

When I click the "Show books" button I get the following log message instead of the book values:

> [ [Ljava.lang.Object;@43395a7b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@aff89fb,
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@76f41bc8]

Comment: Please post your full code, snippets do not tell the full story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `books` contains list of `Object`. If you execute following line of code `console.log(books);`, then Java will go to every object in that list and call `toString()` method on every and each object. And Object by default returns that kind of the output which you can already see.

You should change `List<Object> books = booksService.findAll();` to something more concrete, perhaps `List<String> books = booksService.findAll();`?

To answer that question we should know what will be returned by your service.

You should create a DTO (Data transfer object (DTO), formerly known as value objects or VO, is a design pattern used to transfer data between software application subsystems. DTOs are often used in conjunction with data access objects to retrieve data from a database.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object and use it instead of Object in your list.

Please remember to override toString method if you choose to use your own DTO, instead of String.

```
public class Books {
    private String name;
    private int length;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Books{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", length=" + length +
                '}';
    }
}
```